# iCal does not open correctly invites sent from Outlook

Tags: ical

When someone from Outlook sends an invite is shows at incorrect time in my iCal. I looks like it doesn't take the timezone of the sender into account. If i open the same .ics file with Outlook then the time zone is recognized properly an the meeting is set at the correct time.

Any idea what's wrong with iCal and what can i do to se the proper dates? I don't want to switch to Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

In iCal

1. Go to **Preferences**
2. Enable **Turn on Time Zone support**

Comment: Don't forget to give some points to someone you answered their question.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. All that that does it is to show me my meeting in different time zone depending on what i select. But the meeting i received it's still in wrong time while if i import it in Outlook it looks ok.

Comment: Time Zone support does not make any difference. I have exactly the same problem. Every calendar invite from my European colleagues is fine in Outlook, but off by 8-9 hrs in iCal. Very frustrating.